# Logging from thread: Thread exits when logging to INFO and higher, runs normally when logging to DEBUG

Tags: python, logging, python-2.7, concurrency

I'm writing a program that offers a PySide UI.
In it, a thread is started that sets of a range of functions that are supposed to run in the background, while the UI shows a progress bar.

I am using the backport of Python 3's `concurrent.futures` for Python 2.7 for multithreading.

Here's what the UI method looks like:

```
def doPostprocess(self):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(othermodule.func)
        while not future.done():
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
            self.progressbar.setValue(1)
            time.sleep(0.001)
    self.progressbar.hide()
```

This is what my minimal `othermodule.func` looks like:

```
def func():
    logger.info("Some informational message")
    time.sleep(15)
    print "And we are done here"
```

"We are done here" is never printed to stdout, nevertheless the `future` object signals it is done immediately after the call to `logger.info`.

The funny thing is: When I change the call to `logger.debug`, everything works as expected, i.e. `func` logs, sleeps for 15 seconds and then prints to stdout, all the while the main thread updates its progress bar. This happens no matter what loglevel is set for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your logger object configured? It is possible to configure different handlers for different log levels and they could be failing. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/logging/#configuring-logging

Also look at this note http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#thread-safety. May be the case.

**Update**:

You may also try to use catch-all exception handler to see what's going on inside your thread. Some thing like this:

```
def func():
    try:
        logger.info("Some informational message")
        time.sleep(15)
        print "And we are done here"
    except:
        print "We are interrupted"
        pprint.pprint(sys.exc_info())
```

**Update2:**

As seen in http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/af18829a7754/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#l343. `done()` method returns only status of worker and doesn't raise exception.

You could check if there was exception with `exception()` method of future. Also this will remove unnecessary exception handling from `func()`.

Your code could be (reraising exception from worker):

```
def doPostprocess(self):
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(othermodule.func)
    while not future.done():
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        self.progressbar.setValue(1)
        time.sleep(0.001)
    if future.exception() is not None:
        raise future.exception()
self.progressbar.hide()
```

Comment: Maybe you can also quote the parts that are useful in this answer.

Comment: It's all very basic: Just ``logging.basicConfig(loglevel=logging.INFO)`` (though the level, as I said, doesn't matter). Nothing is explicitely configured otherwise, I did neither add new handlers nor remove old ones. Also, the ``signal`` module is not used in my application, so I don't think that that note applies :-/

Comment: @jbaiter, I've updated post. Hope it'll shed some light to what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the tip with the catch-all exception, I wasn't aware that Python was just silently omitting exceptions in threads without even printing to stderr... Is that documented somewhere?! Turned out I forgot to comment out one part of a method that added a custom logging handler, that had a bug... It works now :-)

Comment: @jbaiter another suggestion for exception handling

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'll be doing now :-)